# Need help on joining three queries for ordering

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I currently have two queries, one for selecting friends and the 2nd for selecting messages for both recipient & sender, how ever because they are three queries in total it doesn't allow me to order them via the message.date / time.
While for the recipient's message I will need to have a seperate tag to align left, and the sender's message to align right.

Here are my queries:

The User.ID being 75 in the queries is the logged in user, which I will replace with

```html
".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]."
```

```html
SELECT IF(friends.sender = 75, friends.recipient, friends.sender) AS user_id
FROM friends
WHERE friends.sender = 75
    OR friends.recipient = 75
```

Sender message

```
SELECT message, sender, recipient FROM message WHERE recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]." AND sender = $FriendName->id ORDER BY message.date DESC, message.time DESC
```

Recipients message

```
SELECT message, sender, recipient FROM message WHERE sender = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]." AND recipient = $FriendName->id ORDER BY message.date DESC, message.time DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
$userid = $_SESSION["user"]["id"];

$sql = "SELECT message, sender, recipient FROM message 
        WHERE (recipient = $userid AND sender = $FriendName->id)
        OR    (sender = $userid AND recipient = $FriendName->id) 
        ORDER BY message.date DESC, message.time DESC
```

I dont see why you need the first query.  When you are iterating through the results you can check the `sender` and `recepient` to figure it out.  And based on that you set the class of your container div to `msg_left` or `msg_right`.

In your css define these to do the formatting you want.